# from :hover to a togglebutton in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover

**What I am trying to do:**

I have a card that when hovered over expands and does a bunch of different animations i worked on. this is great for desktop and not mobile. So when the screen is a certain res I make a toggle button visible. I want this button in react to when clicked on enable the save:hover State its grabbing from my css.

**The Problem**

The button is inside the card aleady and everything in the css is setup for the parent div card.

**my code structure simplified**

```
<div className="card">
    <-- CODE HERE -->
    <Button className="myToggleButton" />
<div/>
```

I cant from what i can tell in css exclusively say myToggleButton:focus do these changes to the following classes since they are parent ones. So i think my only other way to do that is by telling it in react somehow to say that my div is in :hover state, but I can't quite figure out how despite my efforts. Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Why can't you just add the animation class to the card when you press the button?

Comment: could you please elaborate how i would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of activating your animation with the `:hover` pseudo class, you can simply add or toggle another custom class, which would contain the values to transition or keyframes to animate, to the card element when the button is clicked.  In this example I just use a transition, but you could also employ a more complex keyframe animation.

```js
const card = document.querySelector(".card");
const button = document.querySelector(".card > button");

const animate = () => {
  card.classList.toggle("small");
  card.classList.toggle("big");
}

button.addEventListener("click", animate);
```

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.small {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.big {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card small">
  My Amazing Card
  <button>Animate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Made my life a lot easier

Comment: I am trying to animate on this principle but having difficulty. a lot of child classes animate under the hover of the card. how would I be able to set so changing the parent class would animate those things?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  I will suggest that you post a new question with your code.